# prove from Lindelof to seprable

Tags: general-topology

Consider X is metrizable.
Prove that if X is Lindel'o'f, then X is seprable?

I started my prove with assuming that  (X, d) is Lindel¨of.
Then I took the collection {B_d(x, 1/n) | x ∈ D_n} with n∈ N/{0}" N natural numbers" . So I do not know how to prove that this collection covers X. And then how to show that the union of D_n is a countable dense subset of X. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: It's trivial your collection covers $X$: for every $x$ at least $x \in B_d(x,\frac{1}{n})$, and this set is in your cover.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be metrizable. For each $n$, the set $\{B_{1/n}(x):x\in X\}$ is an open cover for $X$. Lindelof $\implies$ this reduces to a countable subcover $\{B_{1/n}(x_i):i\in\mathbb{N}\}$. Let $C_n=\{x_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (the the of centers). Then $C=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}C_n$ is countable. To show it is dense, let $y\in X$ and $\epsilon>0$ both be arbitrary. Let $N$ be such that $1/N<\epsilon$. Since $\{B_{1/N}(x_i):i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ covers $X$, $y\in B_{1/N}(x_j)$ for some $j$. But then $d(x_j,y)<1/N<\epsilon\implies x_j\in B_{\epsilon}(y)\cap C_n$ and so $C_n$ is dense.